# May I reuse the same figure in a different paper?

Tags: graphics, publishability

May I reuse a figure from one of my previous paper?

Or should I ask for the permission to the journal in which that paper is published?

The figure is not a plot but a diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have given up copyright then you need to ask. A diagram is more than a "few words" and can be considered a "complete work" in its own right: "A picture is worth a thousand words."

If you still hold copyright then you can use it freely. In fact, your copyright transfer agreement might actually already give you a license for such things.

In either case, however, you need to cite the original.

---

Caveat: Copyright law varies around the world.

Comment: Some (open access) publishers also use creative commons licenses, which means you can use it according to the license.

Comment: +1 "In either case, however, you need to cite the original." - Very important, independently of copyright!!